# How do I create CNAME records in AWS if the domain is hosted elsewhere?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, domain, cname-record, amazon-route53

I have a domain that is hosted from a provider other than AWS.  I cannot input the CNAME entries that I need there because I'm using custom nameservers:

ns-743.awsdns-28.net
ns-1077.awsdns-06.org
ns-246.awsdns-30.com
ns-2021.awsdns-60.co.uk

When I try to find anything about updating CNAME entries in AWS, it always seems to be through Route 53, but I don't own any domains in Route 53.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Had you give the real name involved, you would have far better and precise answers. Other than that your DNS provider should be able to help you for your DNS setup.

Comment: If those are your custom name servers then yes, you are using Route 53. What you mean to say is that you have a domain that is **registered** with a different provider than AWS. But AWS is hosting the records according to your custom name servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ns-743.awsdns-28.net`, `ns-1077.awsdns-06.org`, `ns-246.awsdns-30.com`, or `ns-2021.awsdns-60.co.uk` as your nameservers then you "ARE" using Route 53 at some point along the way.

If you are sure those nameserver values are accurate, you'll need to figure out which AWS account is handling those records and edit them in Route 53 because that's where the actual host records will live.

---

Alternatively, if you want to configure your CNAME, A, etc records in your "other provider", then you'll need to remove those "nameserver" records that point to Route 53 (awsdns) and configure them appropriately for that provider. **You can ask the provider (or refer to their docs) for what the default nameserver values** are supposed to be.

For example, if you're using Namecheap, you can search Google for "namecheap default nameservers" to find the info without having to contact Namecheap. Do that for whatever your provider actually is. Sometimes you don't even need to know the values and you can just revert to the default in the provider configuration (which will wipe out custom settings).

Comment: "you can search Google for "namecheap default nameservers" to find the info without having to contact Namecheap. " I wouldn't suggest anyone to do that, as you can't vouch in anyway for the accuracy of that information. You should go on the relevant provider website (and you shouldn't need to use Google for that...) and search for information there, or use their control panel or use their support service to raise questions.